# Can you recommend an evening purification puja?

Tags: puja

I am a most recent devotee living in america.  I know little of Hindu faith, religion beliefs or practices other than what has come to me from sources I do not yet understand. I began my practice of Purana Achmanam on 01, Chaitra in the morning. I wish to purify myself of any evil or violence which may have I have created during the day.  I also wish to purify myself if possible of karmas from my other past lives as well, I know there to have been many and in many I was not a good person. thank you for your help and consideration.

Comment: Best Mantra for purification is the Gayatri Mantra, but sadly requires upanayanam, initiation into it from a Guru who himself has unlocked it(performed many sadhanas and made the mantra his own) for it to work for you as soon as possible.Maybe as a start you can try visiting your nearest Iskcon/Swaminarayan Temple where they do initiate you first into the Hare krishna Mahamantra(fantastic too for purification and developing divine love for Lord Krishna!) then into the Gayatri as you progress(i think it is given to the advanced disciples afaik)! Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and consideration with the time you have taken to share with me. Namaskaram.